# Adding "generated sources root" markers for Android Studio from build.gradle.kts

Tags: android-studio, gradle, kotlin-multiplatform

I am writing a KMM app, currently using Android Studio Giraffe and Gradle 8.0. The project includes some simple custom tasks to generate kotlin source code, so I want to mark the relevant directories as "generated sources root". To avoid the markers disappearing when I clean the build I want to apply the markers from my gradle script. According to [Gradle's documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/8.0/dsl/org.gradle.plugins.ide.idea.model.IdeaModule.html) this should be quite easy with the `idea` plugin, by adding this to the relevant module's `build.gradle.kts`:

```kotlin
plugins {
    ...
    idea
}

idea {
    module {
        generatedSourceDirs += File("$buildDir/$licenceInfoDestPath")
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work. I can't invoke `idea` like that. The only `idea` symbol available in the script at all is the property in the `plugins` block, which is shorthand for `id("org.gradle.idea")`, and it's invalid elsewhere in the script.

I've been going round in circles with Bard, trying all sorts of things, like adding `idea` to the top-level script's `plugins` instead of or in addition to the module level, moving the `idea {...}` block to the top-level too, using `apply` instead of `id`. Nothing works.

Then I thought I might be able to get an instance of `IdeaModule` from a custom task, but Bard got that all wrong too, suggesting I can find it in `project.modules`, but `project` doesn't have a `modules` field.

Bard's only other suggestion is to forget the idea plugin and "communicate that information to the IDE," by some other means (including leveraging a gradle plugin, doh!).

Can anyone offer a working solution to this problem?